# Controller not creating DataContext, FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So Im learning MVC and EF7 Code First, by creating a blog. And I keep get a 500 Internal Server Error each time i click the send blog post button, which should create a new local database and insert the post. The View sending the form data to the controller works fine I've checked it with a breakpoint, but it breaks on this row

```
var db = new BlogDataContext();
```

This is my BlogDataContext

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class BlogDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }

        public BlogDataContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        } /// This row is marked red on my error page after i press the send blog post button

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            var connectionString = @"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=test;";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();

        }

    }
}
```

Relevant method from my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Post post)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(post);
            }

            post.PostedDate = DateTime.Now; // Breakpoint here shows the datetime just fine after pressing the Send button.
            post.Author = User.Identity.Name; // This is null for now

            var db = new BlogDataContext();                 db.Post.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
```

Picture of error page
[image: Picture of Error page]

I also made sure that MSSQLLocalDB was started
[image: MSSQLLOCALDB started]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my dependencies were wrong, I had my DNX version to beta5 and my entityframework.sqlserver was beta4, so I upgraded it to beta5, but got error on OnConfiguring and DbContextOptionsBuilder. It cant find that override.

So i just turned everything back to beta4, and it works, altough site is loading slower in iis express.